# Enumerate index not recognized in function, "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ix' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, function, scope

In different functions of a scraper, I use the same variable name `ix` for `enumerate`. For instance:

```
def func():
    for ix, i in range(5):
        print(ix, i)
```

However, it results in an error.

> NameError: name 'ix' is not defined

Here is the code of the scraper, you can clearly see that `ix` is defined. See the `<<<<<<<` in the code to find the error

```py
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import numpy as np

website = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com"
alphabet = 'uywz'  # do not include x

def fetch(page, addition=''):
    """Fetches HTML data"""
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; Ub'
               'untu/14.10) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16'}
    req = Request(page + addition, headers=headers)
    open_request = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(open_request, 'lxml')
    return soup

def critics_letters(letters):
    """Creates URL for 26 pages of critics, based on the first letter of their name"""
    letters_url = list()
    for elem in letters:
        letters_url.append("/critics/authors?letter=" + elem)
    return letters_url

def critics_list(catalog):
    """Fetches the url of all listed critics"""
    critics_url = list()
    for ix, letter_pages in enumerate(catalog, 1):
        for p in fetch(website, letter_pages).find_all("p", {"class": "critic-names"}):
            for a in p.find_all("a"):
                href_critic = a['href']
                if str(href_critic)[:7] != "/source":
                    critics_url.append(href_critic + "/movies")
        print('\r1/4 — {:.2%} of movie critic URLs scraped.'.format(ix/len(catalog)), end='   ')
    print('\r{} pages of movie critic URLs successfully scraped.'.format(ix), end='  '); print()
    return critics_url

def movies(catalog):
    """Fetches the url of the movies reviewed by the critic"""
    movies_url = list()
    errors = 0
    for ix, critic_profile in enumerate(catalog, 1):               # ASSIGNMENT HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        try:
            checker = fetch(website, critic_profile).find_all("h2", {"class": "panel-heading js-review-type"})
            if len(checker) > 0:
                if checker[0].text == "Movie Reviews Only":
                    for td in fetch(website, critic_profile).find_all("td",
                                    {"class": "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 critic-review-table__title-column"}):
                        for a in td.find_all("a"):
                            if a['href'] not in movies_url:
                                movies_url.append(a['href'])
        except:
            errors += 1
        print('\r2/4 — {:.2%} of movie URLs scraped. Error rate: {:.2%}'.format(ix/len(catalog),
                                        errors/ix), end='   ')
    print('\r{} movie URLs successfully scraped. Error rate: {:.2%}'.format(
        len(movies_url)-errors, errors/ix), end='\n')            # ERROR RAISE HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    return movies_url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    critic_main = critics_letters(alphabet)
    list_critics = critics_list(critic_main)
    all_movies = movies(list_critics)
```

Why is that, and why isn't the error raised at the first use of `ix`? I did a bit of research and I can avoid this error by using `global ix` before `enumerate`, but is it a good idea?
See the full code here: [scraping all critic reviews from rotten tomatoes](https://github.com/nicolas-gervais/6-607-Algorithms-for-Big-Data-Analysis/blob/master/scraping%20all%20critic%20reviews%20from%20rotten%20tomatoes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing a variable defined in a for loop after the loop body:

```
for foo in range(5):
    pass
print(foo)  # prints 4
```

If the for loop is never executed (the iterable doesn't contain any elements) then the variable will not be defined

```
for foo in []:
    pass
print(foo)  # NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: You're right, all this time I was looking at globals and everything. It appears Rotten Tomatoes changed their configuration again, probably to prevent my intensive scraping.